# unable to update on remote mysql table

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to perform an update on a remote mysql table using xampp. i have implemented it as an RMI application. i have also implemented a method addDoctor which works fine. but when i run the updateDoctor method from a client GUI it says to me that the record has been updated (no error) but when i check the database it does not reflect the changes.

```
public void updateDoctor(int id, String name) throws RemoteException{
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospital_db", "root", "");
        String sql = "UPDATE doctor SET doctor_name=? WHERE doctor_id=? ";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        ps.setString(2, name);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        con.commit();
        System.out.println("Updated!");
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error: "+e);
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Error: "+e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the `doctor_id` value exist in the table? You can assign the return value of `executeUpdate` to an integer to see how many rows were affected.

Comment: If "Updated" is on the output only tells you that there was no exception. It doesn't imply that the operation was successfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ps.setString(1, name);     
ps.setInt(2, id);
```